# How to use a FutureBuilder that constructs a taller widget in ListView?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a ListView that have a gray box of 200 px tall, when there passes 3 seconds, I want that gray box changes for a blue box of 500 px tall. I used a FutureBuilder for that, but there is a bug in the scrolling, there is an abrupt jump when you scroll down and again scroll up.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Just create a new Flutter app
2. Paste below code in **main.dart**

   ```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

   void main() {
     runApp(MyApp());
   }

   class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return MaterialApp(
         title: 'Flutter Demo',
         theme: ThemeData(
           primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
           visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
         ),
         home: Scaffold(
           body: ListView(
             children: <Widget>[
               FutureBuilder(
                 future: new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () => 'whatevs'),
                 builder: (context, snapshot) {
                   if (snapshot.hasData) {
                     return Container(width: 200, height: 500, color: Colors.blue);
                   } else {
                     return Container(width: 200, height: 200, color: Colors.grey);
                   }
                 },
               ),
               Container(width: 200, height: 500, color: Colors.green),
               Container(width: 200, height: 500, color: Colors.orange),
               Container(width: 200, height: 500, color: Colors.red),
             ],
           ),
         ),
       );
     }
   }
   ```
3. Wait 3 seconds
4. Scroll to the bottom
5. Scroll up again and see the jump in the green box

How can I remove this undesired jump and make scroll smooth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `init` method rather than a `Future` in `Build Widget`. The widget will be built every time any event triggers like you when you touch the screen. That's the reason for the jump.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
    }
    
    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
      bool loaded = false;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        // TODO: implement initState
        super.initState();
        Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)).then((value) => {
              //Do more things
              setState(() {
                loaded = true;
              })
            });
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
          ),
          home: Scaffold(
            body: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                loaded
                    ? Container(width: 200, height: 500, color: Colors.blue)
                    : Container(width: 200, height: 200, color: Colors.grey),
                Container(width: 200, height: 500, color: Colors.green),
                Container(width: 200, height: 500, color: Colors.orange),
                Container(width: 200, height: 500, color: Colors.red),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```